# ESRI Javascript KMLLayer and CSVLayer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml, csv

I have a map where I have a KMLLayer that defines a geographic boundary and a CSVLayer that defines points within that boundary. I do not want any infoWindow information popping up for the KMLLayer and want to take some actions on the click event on the CSVLayer.

In building this page, I have found that I can no longer apply a click event to the CSVLayer once I have added the KMLLayer to the map.

Seems like it would not be too difficult... but I have played with multiple instances of this and keep coming back to the same place.

```
var map, kml, csv;  
        require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/KMLLayer", "esri/layers/CSVLayer", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/urlUtils", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils", "esri/geometry/screenUtils", "esri/geometry/ScreenPoint", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, KMLLayer, CSVLayer, SimpleRenderer, InfoTemplate, urlUtils, PictureMarkerSymbol, Point, SpatialReference, webMercatorUtils, screenUtils, ScreenPoint, dom, array) {  
            map = new Map("map", {  
                basemap : "hybrid",  
                center : [-83.71, 36.05],  
                zoom : 8  
            });  

            map.on("load", function() {  
                map.infoWindow.set('anchor', 'bottom-right');  
                map.infoWindow.resize(625, 425);  
            });  
            map.infoWindow.on("hide", centerMap);  

            urlUtils.addProxyRule({  
                proxyUrl : "/proxy/proxy.php",  
                urlPrefix : "www.srh.noaa.gov"  
            });  

            var template = new InfoTemplate("${name}", "<iframe src=${fcstlink} class="fcst"></iframe>");  
            var csvUrl = "http://www.srh.noaa.gov/images/rtimages/mrx/js_local/riverpoints.csv";  
            csv = new CSVLayer(csvUrl, {  
                copyright : "weather.gov",  
                infoTemplate : template  
            });  
            var logo = new PictureMarkerSymbol("http://www.srh.noaa.gov/images/mrx/surf.png", 20, 20);  
            var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(logo);  
            csv.setRenderer(renderer);  
            map.addLayer(csv);  
            csv.on("click", mapFcstAction);  

            var kmlUrl = "http://www.srh.noaa.gov/images/rtimages/mrx/kml/RiversLakes.kml";  
            kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);  
            map.addLayer(kml);  

            kml.on('load', function(lyr) {  
                var layers = lyr.layer.getLayers();  
                array.forEach(layers, function(l) {  
                    l.setInfoTemplate(null);  
                });  
            });  

            function centerMap() {  
                alert("CENTER");  
                map.graphics.clear();  
                map.centerAt([-83.71, 36.05]);  
            }  

            function mapFcstAction(evt) {  
                alert("FCST");  
                map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint);  
                var screenX = evt.screenPoint.x;  
                var screenY = evt.screenPoint.y;  
                var newScreenX = screenX + 225;  
                var newScreenY = screenY + 250;  
                var newScreenCenter = screenUtils.toMapPoint(map.extent, 800, 550, new ScreenPoint(newScreenX, newScreenY));  
                map.centerAt(newScreenCenter);  
            }  
        });
```

Comment: Try to add first the KML layer before the  CSV layer to the map .

Comment: Layer order does not matter. Same results... cannot get the csv click event to occur.